# Celery Flower - tasks not shown when I define tasks by custom task classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

now I'm using celery and flower for async jobs.

when I define tasks.py like this:

```py
import os
import time

from celery import Celery, Task


celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://localhost:6379")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://localhost:6379")


@celery.task(name="create_task")
def create_task(task_type):
    time.sleep(int(task_type) * 10)
    return True
```

the executed tasks are shown on ${flower host}/tasks, but

when I define `create_task()` like this, executed tasks aren't shown on ${flower host}/tasks.

```py
class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self, task_type):
        time.sleep(int(task_type) * 10)
        return True

create_task = celery.register_task(MyTask())
```

both of them are executed tasks successfully, and I can see the number of executed task from here:

[image]

and as I can see from the documentation, the definition of tasks are fine.
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes

what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason,
when I execute a task, I need to specify the name of args (in this case, `task_type`) explicitly.

```py
    task = create_task.delay(task_type=int(task_type))
```

sorry for my TED Talk.